# spring cloud zuul ouath2 password authentication

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

i am currently building a security solution in spring cloud microservices.

when combining springs OAuth2 and Zuul implementation, it is quite easy to build an authenticationprocess like:

- user calls the ui, which knows initially: user is not authenticated
- redirect to auth server to ask the user for his login creds
- redirects him back to the ui, providing a code or token.

I would prefer a flow with password authentication  flow, in a way where the auth server is behind zuul

For example:

- 1.2.3.4:8080 is Zuul (with a UI with angularJS), domain "example.com"
- 1.2.3.5:9000 is the Auth Server

I could configure the zuul in a way, to access 1.2.3.5:9000 directly, passing form fields AND basic authentication to pass the client id.

since the auth server registers itself to eureka, I could also use "example.com/auth_server", which is the same, but managed through zuul. Alternatively I could also configure it manually....nevertheless:

Password authentication does not work, since Zuul is removing the basic authentication header from call....

at this point, I see I am doing something wrong...because the edge serve COULD have it's own security solution and tunneling the basic authentication to auth may be not the best way....but

HOW can I manage password authentication with ouath2 through zuul?

Please Help :)

Answer (score 0):

By default "Cookie", "Set-Cookie", "Authorization" are marked as sensitive headers on a route and are not forwarded. Setting `zuul.routes.myroute.sensitiveHeaders=''` should allow you to pass those headers through, though I'm not sure it's the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a late working session in the evening :)

The component making the request didn't send the authorization since some updates which led to no headers ever reached the edge server.

Obviously, everything works as intended if basic or bearer authorization headers are passed over